# Can you use a web service as a datasource for a mailmerge

Tags: web-services, ms-word, reporting, word-field

Some clients of ours want to use data (SQL Server backend) in a web application we've developed to generate some documents (agreements, contracts, etc).  They'd also prefer to have the document templates to be in a form they are familiar with and can easily generate new ones.  My initial thought was to create a SQL Server Reporting Services data model which they could consume however they please but SSRS may be a barrier to them.

They are familiar with Microsoft Word and MailMerge however, so I was wondering if there is way to use a webservice as a MailMerge datasource or if there are any other suggestions to accomplish the following:

1. Have our medium tech-savvy clients be able to create and manage document templates (don't have to be Word) that user data in our database
2. Get our database to expose the data to their templates

Comment: What technology / language is it you are trying to get this task done it?

Answer (score 0):

If you've got budget, you might check out Windward Reports. I evaluated it for a law firm that was looking for very much what you're describing. Then ended up needing more specialized functions that what Windward could do, but after reviewing it, it's quite capable.

But, it's a bit pricy. Still, might be cheaper than building something.

Answer (score 0):

Late, but there's a [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) web service you could try which you send it your templates and your data and it streams back documents (merged).  It might be what you were after...